# Save image from frame data to file in R

Tags: r, file, save, jpeg

I made something like this to read images:

```
path <- "C:\\Users\\me\\Desktop\\images" 
jpgFiles <- list.files(path, pattern="*jpg$", full.name=TRUE)
jpgList <- lapply(jpgFiles, readJPEG)
```

Now I want do the same but instead of readeing I want to save images from jpgList to a new folder. 
How can I do this?

Comment: I usually use a `for` loop. Something like `for(fileNum in seq_along(jpgList)) saveFUN(file.path(path, paste0("myOutFile", fileNum)), jpgList[[fileNum]])`.

Comment: You can copy with `file.copy()`. This [help page](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/files.html) explains other manipulations you can do